# Spellchecking other languages than default in Live Mail 2011

Tags: language, spell-check, windows-live-mail

My buddy is using Microsoft Live Mail 2011. The challenge is: this is a basically German setup - so the menus and dialogs and all are German.

He also needs to write e-mails in English and French, and would like to also spell-check these e-mails before sending.

Under `Options > E-Mail > Spelling`, you can define what languages are supported by the spellchecker. We made sure we have all the German, French an English languages installed and ready.

**BUT:** even with this setup, while German e-mails are spellchecked correctly, anything we type in English is shown with a red squiggly underline....

What I've been unable to find is how to tell the e-mail editor that this is an **ENGLISH** text now so that the English spell checker would be used.

We even went so far as to set one of the English languages as the **default** (using the `Set Default` button in the options dialog) -> same result. Gemran is spellchecked correctly, all English text is underlined as mistakes....

How on earth can we teach Live Mail to either use **all** installed languages when spell-checking, or how can we define that a given e-mail is German, another one is English, and a third is French??